# Присвоение вариантного массива диапазону ячеек в Excel

Tags: excel, c++, visual-studio

Пытаюсь разобраться с вариантными массивами в c++.

Код:

```
VARIANT v;  
SAFEARRAYBOUND rgb[] = {10,0};  
v.vt = VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT;  
v.parray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_VARIANT,1,rgb);  
long *rgelems;   
SafeArrayAccessData(v.parray, (void**)&rgelems);  
for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
{rgelems[c] = c*100;}  
SafeArrayUnaccessData(v.parray);   
for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)  
{std::cout << rgelems[c] << " ";}    
Excel::RangePtr pRange = OldSheet->Range["A1"]["A10"];  
pRange->Value2 = rgelems;
```

Не пойму ворнинг компилятора

> warning C4800: long *: принудительно
> задано логическое значение "true" или
> "false"

(предупреждение о производительности) - ссылается на строку

```
Range->Value2 = rgelems;
```

И в Excel в указанный диапазон пишется значение "ИСТИНА", хотя при выводе в консоль выводятся нормальные значения. В чем проблема?
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: @OverDozero: Не могу найти документацию, поэтому спрошу вас: а какого типа `Value2`?

Comment: VladD,Не совсем понял вопрос:что значит какого типа value2?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2.aspx
Отличие Value2 от Value в том, что Value2 не поддерживает "форматирования на лету" для типов Currency, Double и Date
Мне кажется тут именно проблема присвоении диапазону.Я пробовал присваивать массиву символы,допустим "!".Тогда в диапазон выводит нормально,а именно для чисел - "ИСТИНА".Например мне необходимо заполнить в экселе 65000 строк цифрам от 1 до 65000.Поячеечно это довольно долго,а при присвоении диапазона получаю 65000 строк истины)